# ¿Cómo generar un archivo ipa en modo desarrollador pero con firmas y certificados?

Tags: ios, xcode

Tengo un problema.

Necesito hacer debbug de una app, pero cuando genero el archivo ipa (en xcode) **en modo desarrollo**, no puedo abrir la app en iphone, me muestra un mensaje que dice "no se puede verificar la integridad", investigando descubrí que esto pasa porque le faltan las firmas y certificados.

Si genero el ipa en **modo Enterprise**, se instala y se abre correctamente, pero en dicho modo no se puede hacer debug.

¿Alguien tiene alguna idea?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por qué no conectas el iPhone al Xcode y así pruebas la app?

Answer (score 0):

Checa estos puntos que son necesarios para firmar tu aplicación :

1. Certificado de Desarrollo:
   Si no lo tienes crea uno desde el panel de control de tu cuenta de iOS :
   Certificates -> “+” para Crear certificado -> Seleccionar iOS Development y crea tu certificado
2. Dispositivo registrado
   Tienes que tener tu **UDID** del dispositivo registrado en la sección de *"Devices"*  en el panel de tu
   cuenta de iOS , en la licencia de desarrollador son 100 dispositivos como máximo.
   Si seleccionas la opción *"Automatically manage signing"* te registrará todos los dispositivos que tengas registrados.
   Solo podrás abrir la aplicación en estos.

[image: Opciones para creacion de modo desarrollo del IPA]
￼

3. También debes tener tu perfil provisional de tu aplicación, pero si en el punto de arriba seleccionas la
   opción de *"Automatically manage signing"* te ahorras esto.